# Find limit of integral with given value

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

We have a given equation:

$$\int_0^\alpha f(x)\ dx = \theta$$

with $f(x)$ and $\theta$ given.

$$\theta>0,$$
$$f(x) > 0 \text{ for all } x$$

What would be the most generic way to calculate $\alpha$? Numerical methods are allowed.

If no generic way exists, how could we calculate it for eg. $f(x) = \sin^2 x + 1$?

Comment: Newton's method should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **Welcome to the site !**

As already said in comments and answers, *most* of the time, you will need a numerical method and Newton will be the simplest (just remember that $x=\cos(x)$ does not show solutions).

For sure, I admit that you have been able to compute the required antiderivative.
$$\int f(x)\ dx =F(x) \implies\int_0^\alpha f(x)\ dx = \theta \implies F(\alpha)= F(0)+\theta $$

Starting for a *reasonable* guess $\alpha_0$, the method will update it according to
$$\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_{n}-\frac{F(\alpha_{n})-F(0)- \theta} {f(\alpha_{n})}$$

For the simle example you give, you have
$$F(x)=\frac{3 }{2}x-\frac{1}{4} \sin (2 x)$$ which will give, after some trigonometric simplifications,
$$\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_{n}+\frac{ \sin (2 \alpha_{n} )-6 \alpha_{n}+4 \theta }{3-2 \cos (2 \alpha_{n} )}$$ and a simple guess could be $\alpha_0=\frac 23\theta$.

Let us try using $\theta=123.456$. Then, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \alpha_{n} \\
 0 & 82.3040000000000 \\
 1 & 82.4807566822034 \\
 2 & 82.4706953627373 \\
 3 & 82.4706617145300 \\
 4 & 82.4706617141536
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(\alpha) := \int_0^{\alpha} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \theta$. You are looking for the zeroes of $F$. There are standard numerical methods to find zeroes of differentiable functions, e.g. bisection or Newton's method. Of course you would need numerical integration to evaluate $F$ unless you know the anti-derivative of $f$ like in your example case.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$  g(\alpha) = \int_0^\alpha f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$
You want to find zeroes of $g(\alpha) - \theta$.

First, you should determine whether there are any solutions.  By the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part), $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}g(\alpha) = f(\alpha)$.  Since $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, $g$ is a monotonically increasing function.  Consequently, for a solution to exist, you must have 
$$  \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow -\infty} g(\alpha) < \theta < \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} g(\alpha)  \text{.}  $$
Generically, I would start with [Gauss-Laguerre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Laguerre_quadrature) for these two integrals over semi-infinite intervals.  Alternatively, use a [change of variables to a finite interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Integrals_over_infinite_intervals) and then use [tanh-sinh quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature).

If $\theta$ is not between the two limits, then there is no solution.  Alternatively, there is a solution and we have shown there is an $\alpha \in (-\infty, \infty)$ such that $g(\alpha) = \theta$.  Then since $\int_0^0 \dots = 0$, if $\theta = 0$, we report $\alpha = 0$ as the solution.  If $0 < \theta$, the solution is in $(0,\infty)$, otherwise the solution is in $(-\infty, 0)$.  If not finished, use [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) to reduce the semi-infinite interval to a finite interval containing the solution, then use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) to reduce that interval until you reach your precision and accuracy goals.

Note that there are many improvements that can be made if $f$ has particular features.

For your example, \begin{align*}
f(x) &= 1 + \sin^2 x  \\
g(\alpha) &= \int_0^\alpha \; 1+\sin^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow -\infty} g(\alpha) &= - \infty  \\
\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} g(\alpha) &= \infty
\end{align*}
So regardless of $\theta$, there is an $\alpha$ in $(-\infty, \infty)$ such that $g(\alpha) = \theta$.  Since $g(0) = 0$, if $\theta = 0$, report $\alpha = 0$ is the solution.  Throughout the following. if an evaluation of $g$ yields $\theta$, report the argument to $g$ as the solution.  Otherwise, for $\theta > 0$, start exponential search in $(0, \infty)$, and for $\theta < 0$, start exponential search in $(-\infty, 0)$.  Since the two continuations are similar via reflection, we continue with $\theta > 0$.  We have $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$.  We test \begin{align*}
g(1) &= 1.272\dots  \\
g(2) &= 3.189\dots  \\
g(4) &= 5.752\dots  \\
g(8) &= 12.07\dots  \\
    &\vdots  \\
g(2^k) &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 3 \cdot 2^k - \cos(2^k)\sin(2^k) \right)
\end{align*}
successively, until we find $k$ such that $g(2^{k-1}) < \theta < g(2^k)$.  (For the generic term in that list, we have used the fact that $g(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}(3\alpha - \cos \alpha \sin \alpha)$, although that this $g$ can be expressed in elementary terms is an accident of your choice of $f$ and should not be expected generally.)  Now we know how long is the binary representation of the magnitude of $\alpha$.  Binary search successively determines the less significant bits.  Continue until you have reached your precision and accuracy goals.